# Adding external source files to PHP IDE

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, phpstorm

I'm trying to setup my development environment and have an issue with including external source files for my project.

The dev environment is on a remote server. With both PHPStorm and Netbeans, I setup a remote project and included /var/www/site as my project location. This downloads the files to my local computer and works fine.

The problem, when I'm stepping through the code, some of the include files are outside the project directory (/etc/includes) and therefore I cannot step into them. Is there a way to include external files into the project for Netbeans and PHPStorm?

I think this is also the cause of me not being able to step through code with Netbeans, it will load the debugging, but I cannot step through, only continue. In PHPStorm I can step through, but error with external files.

Thank you.

Comment: Create local copies of that libraries

Comment: I got it to work by copying the external sources to my local and adding it to the include path and mapping it. Thanks.